# Find duplicate IDs across columns and combine rows together in R

Tags: r, duplicates, dplyr, aggregate

I am working with a historical dataset which identifies fish tag IDs.  Some fish were tagged multiple times over the years and thus have multiple tag IDs associated with the same individual (i.e., a tag was replaced with a new tag).  I would like to identify all the possible tag IDs for each individual fish. There is no unique identifier for each fish; I can only identify associations between tag IDs.  I have managed to clean some of the dataset and identify unique tag IDs in one column and add any associated other tag IDs to additional columns in the same row.  However, duplicates exist *between* the columns.  Here is an example of what my dataset looks like:

```
ID1<-c(101,102,103,105,106,107,108,110,111,112,113,114)
ID2<-c(NA,101,290,309,105,108,NA,220,NA,113,112,112)
ID3<-c(NA,NA,400,106,NA,NA,NA,111,NA,NA,NA,NA)
data<-data.frame(ID1,ID2,ID3)
```

```
    ID1   ID2  ID3 
1   101    NA   NA
2   102   101   NA     
3   103   290  400    
4   105   309  106     
5   106   105   NA    
6   107   108   NA  
7   108    NA   NA
8   110   220  111  
9   111    NA   NA
10  112   113   NA
11  113   112   NA
12  114   112   NA
```

As you can see in this example, fish 1 would have tag ID 101 and 102 - right now these look like two separate fish if you were only looking at the column ID1, but we know it is the same fish because it also has tag ID 101 associated with tag 102.

My resulting data frame should look something like this:

```
    ID1   ID2  ID3 
1   101   102   NA
2   103   290  400        
3   105   309  106         
4   107   108   NA  
5   110   220  111  
6   112   113  114
```

While there are no duplicated tag IDs within ID1 (first column), duplicates do exist *between* ID1 and ID2, and ID1 and ID3 (no duplicates exist between ID2 and ID3, except for NAs).  There are a few duplicates within ID2 because they are associated with another ID in ID1 (see rows 10:12 in my example above where tag ID 112 shows up once in ID1 and twice in ID2).

I have identified which IDs are duplicated between columns using %in% command, for example

```
data$ID1[data$ID1 %in% data$ID2]
data$ID1[data$ID1 %in% data$ID3]
```

And I've built this into an ifelse statement:

```
ifelse(data$ID1 %in% data$ID2| data$ID1 %in% data$ID3, "Match", "Nomatch")
```

but this only shows me which IDs are duplicated and I'm lost as to how to actually combine the information into one row.

I've also tried separating these data into two different data frames so that I could use a join command, but I lost relevant information.

I was thinking I may need to use aggregate() or perhaps combine() and wrap it into my ifelse statement?  Or perhaps there is a way to do this within dplyr? Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: tough one, will have to try to think about this later.

Comment: This isn't making a lot of sense when I try to translate the data back to a "reality" scenario. How can the data in rows 10 and 11 arise? And PLEASE never use `as.data.frame(cbind(...))`. Just use `data,frame` and you will avoid the errors associated with mixing matrix and dataframe classes.

Comment: It is a large, historical data set, my best guess is that the person entering the data didn't take into consideration that the order the tag IDs get entered mattered.  But I do have instances of this within the file.

Comment: What is not clear to me is how you decided to build the data frame. You said that: "duplicates do exist between ID1 and ID2, and ID1 and ID3 (no duplicates exist between ID2 and ID3, except for NAs)". According to your data example, there are maximum three IDs for the same fish. Is it true for the whole data set? Whether true, I have an inelegant solution for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I identified some omissions from the routines I originally posted which gave rise to the duplicates you found. I have corrected those in the revised code below:

```
data.duplicates = union(intersect(data$ID1, data$ID2), intersect(data$ID1, data$ID3))

data.t = 
  data.frame(t(data)) %>%
  mutate(Cols = rownames(.)) %>%
  gather(key = row, value = ID, starts_with("X"))

data.t.joined = 
  filter(data.t, !is.na(ID)) %>% 
  inner_join(data.t, by = "ID")

data.t.combined =
  data.t.joined %>%
  mutate(row.x = as.integer(gsub("X", "", row.x))) %>%
  select(row.x, ID) %>%
  group_by(row.x) %>%
  summarise(IDs = list(sort(unique(ID))))

mergesubsets <- function(thedata){
  rows = nrow(thedata)
  for (i in 1:rows){
    entry = unlist(thedata$IDs[i])
    for (j in 1:rows){
      if (i!=j){
        otherentry = unlist(thedata$IDs[j])
        if(max(entry %in% otherentry)==1) {
          entry = sort(union(entry, otherentry))
          thedata$IDs[i] = list(entry)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  thedata[!duplicated(thedata$IDs),]
}

listtodataframe <- function(thedata){
  rows = nrow(thedata)
  cols = max(sapply(thedata$IDs, length))
  result = matrix(nrow = rows, ncol = cols)
  for (i in 1:rows){
    entry = unlist(thedata$IDs[i])
    for (j in 1:length(entry)){
      result[i, j] = entry[j]
    }
  }
  data.frame(result)
}


data.t.merged = data.t.combined

prevrows = 0
rows = nrow(data.t.merged)
starttime = proc.time()[3]
while(rows != prevrows) {
  prevrows = rows
  data.t.merged = 
    mergesubsets(data.t.merged)
  rows = nrow(data.t.merged)
}
endtime = proc.time()[3]
timetorun = endtime - starttime 
timetorun


result = listtodataframe(data.t.merged)
result
write.csv(result, "result.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

I have tested the revised code with a different dataset of 500 rows of numeric data which is too big to post here. It now correctly identifies all unique sets of values, no matter how many across these may be. When I've tested with sets of randomised data I've in some cases ended up with a single row which has all the unique values in it.

Sorry to say I have not so far been able to speed up this version, which as you mentioned is time consuming when operating on 11,000 rows. I appreciate that your real data is non-numeric, which is also less efficient to process than numeric data.

My tests have been on 500 rows, taking approx. 25 seconds to complete.

An example of its output from the 500 rows of all-numeric test data is shown below.

```
> result
        X1     X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9   X10   X11   X12   X13
1      100    101   102   103   104   105   200   300    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2      110    113   210   321    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
3      111    211   311    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
4      112    312   412    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
5      500    600   601   602   603   604   605   610   613   700   710   800   821
6      611    711   811    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
7      612    812   912    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
8     1000   1100  1101  1102  1103  1104  1105  1110  1113  1200  1210  1300  1321
9     1111   1211  1311    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
10    1112   1312  1412    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
11    1500   1600  1601  1602  1603  1604  1605  1610  1613  1700  1710  1800  1821
```

Comment: Also, could you please explain starttime = proc.time()[3], specifically what is the [3] indexing?

Comment: I'd need to know the line number on which the error is occurring - I restructured some of the functions so it is not to do with the line you identified that has been replaced. If I could get a copy of your dataset I could identify much more easily what has gone wrong - I did test with 5000 rows of numeric data, but your dataset is not that straightforward as you've previously mentioned. Re the qualifier on proc time, there are three time components returned, and the elapsed time is the third element.

Comment: Thanks @Stewart Ross for your quick reply -- prior to seeing your reply, I deleted my previous comment, as I think I found my error.  It is currently running over the entire dataset.  Crossing my fingers it works!  I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: I think this worked!  It took about 7 hours to run over my data set of 11,852 rows.  And there was 1 fish that had 4 possible IDs and I was unaware of this before, so thanks to the generality of your code, I was able to identify this fish.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you an inelegant solution to your question that fits only with your toy data and the condition you stated: "duplicates do exist between ID1 and ID2, and ID1 and ID3 (no duplicates exist between ID2 and ID3, except for NAs)". 
In fact, according to your data, it seems that there are maximum three duplicated IDs for each fish. For this reason this is my solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Your data:

```
ID1<-c(101,102,103,105,106,107,108,110,111,112,113,114)
ID2<-c(NA,101,290,309,105,108,NA,220,NA,113,112,112)
ID3<-c(NA,NA,400,106,NA,NA,NA,111,NA,NA,NA,NA)
Your data frame:
data <- data.frame(cbind(ID1,ID2,ID3))
```

I create two data frames, on the basis of your statement that affirms there are links between IDs only between ID1 and ID2 or between ID1 and ID3:

```
data1 <- data.frame(cbind(ID1,ID2)) %>% 
    rename(A=ID1,B=ID2)
data2 <- data.frame(cbind(ID1,ID3)) %>% 
    rename(A=ID1,B=ID3)
```

I bind two data frames, and reverse the values of IDs by rows from the minimum to maximum one. So I may select only distinct couples of IDs and I may create the triad of duplicated IDs through some data wrangling operations:

```
bind_rows(data1,data2) %>% 
    filter(complete.cases(.)) %>% 
    mutate(ID1=pmin(A,B),
           ID2=pmax(A,B)) %>% 
    select(ID1,ID2) %>% 
    arrange(ID1,ID2) %>% 
    group_by(ID1) %>% 
    mutate(ID3=max(ID2)) %>% 
    distinct(.) %>% 
    filter(ID2==first(ID2))
```

The result (without NAs):

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups: ID1 [6]
    ID1   ID2   ID3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   101   102   102
2   103   290   400
3   105   106   309
4   107   108   108
5   110   111   220
6   112   113   114
```

Comment: Thank you; this works with the test data.  However, in hindsight, I should have added characters to my sample data, as the tag IDs are character strings and often contain letters as well as numbers.  I didn't consider this while I was creating the sample data -- I was just trying to make sure I captured examples of the ID placement and mistakenly didn't account for the ID structure.  Do you have a recommendation as to how to edit the mutate() function such that it will mutate with characters instead of using integers?

Comment: Also, could you please clarify what filter(ID2==first(ID2)) is doing?  It looks like the code is keeping the first entry of each unique ID in ID2; however, if you run the code up to just before this line (i.e., end at distinct(.)), there are no duplicates in ID2, but there are in ID1.  Am I misinterpreting?

Comment: About the presence of character variables instead of numeric ones into the IDs, I don't have an easy solution. The code I suggested to you works fine because it uses property of numeric values across the rows and columns (function such as `pmin` or `pmax`, and so on). So I have to study the problem to find an alternative solution for characters.

Comment: Theorically, you could create an unique character vector with all IDs, and trasnform it into a factor. Then you may substitute the IDs values (numbers or characters) with the corrispondent levels (numeric values) of created factor into your data frame. I don't know whether it may work, and whether I well explained my idea.

Comment: About your second question: `filter(ID2==first(ID2))` I suggest you to run the code with your example step by step, till each pipe command (not selecting `%>%`). You could understand very easy what the code is doing by comparing the progressive outputs. I think it will help also to understand why I have used `distinct` function.

Comment: Thanks, I have run the code line-by-line without the piping, and I understand up to the point of distinct(.).  Distinct(.) gives you the distinct rows, and the filter(ID2==first(ID2)) takes out the duplicates leaving us with the result.  But when I look at the tibble after running distinct(.) there are duplicates within ID1, but not ID2, so I am confused as to why we are filtering on ID2 and not ID1?

Comment: Because with `mutate(ID1=pmin(A,B),ID2=pmax(A,B))` you take IDs with minimum value and put on ID1 column, than arranging by ID1 and ID2, you need to run `distinct` to eliminate duplicated rows generated by the previous operation. Last one line allows you to choose the first value (so the minimum one) on ID2, this operation allows you to select triade IDs when they are, in all other cases ID2 and ID3 will have the same value. I hope have being enough clear. PS: sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I took your suggestion and created a factor vector with all IDs, then substituted the IDs values with the corresponding factor levels. This worked for the example data (I added an "X" to the end of all of the numbers and made it a character string, and R read it automatically as factors), but it did not work for the entire dataset.  If an ID was not a duplicate, such that it was only found once in ID1 and it had 2 different associated IDs- in ID2 and ID3 (so 3 unique IDs total), then it split into two lines such that ID1 and ID2 were paired and ID1 and ID3 were paired, but not all together

Comment: It would have been helpful for me have been working on your original data set to better understand its structure. In any case, I'm pleased to know you have solved. Best wishes

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a different approach to this problem, which I've viewed as related to generating sets of ID values from the data you provided. I make no assumptions about the three ID columns being distinct or otherwise in the solution proper. The solution also makes no assumptions about the number of columns that would result from being applied to the real data - if there are more than three entries in any of the result sets the data frame with the results will increase in its number of columns to accommodate these accordingly.

I have replicated the results requested using a combination of tidyverse functions and loop processing for the sets. @Scipione's answer is a good demonstration of using the tidyverse functions alone to do all this, but as he mentions the solution was in line with the data in the example; I wanted to generalise as much as possible using a set-based approach instead.

As in @Scipione's answer, I start with your data, then identify the duplicate IDs using set union to do so. These are not used further in the solution below, but these may be of interest in their own right:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

ID1<-c(101,102,103,105,106,107,108,110,111,112,113,114)
ID2<-c(NA,101,290,309,105,108,NA,220,NA,113,112,112)
ID3<-c(NA,NA,400,106,NA,NA,NA,111,NA,NA,NA,NA)
data<-data.frame(ID1,ID2,ID3)

data.duplicates = union(intersect(ID1, ID2), intersect(ID1, ID3))

> data.duplicates
[1] 101 105 108 112 113 106 111
```

So, in the sample data there are seven IDs which appear more than once in columns ID1 and ID2 or ID1 and ID3.

To start the generation of ID rows proper, I transpose the data then convert the result to long format, then self-join the table on the IDs:

```
data.t = 
  data.frame(t(data)) %>%
  mutate(Cols = rownames(.)) %>%
  gather(key = row, value = ID, starts_with("X"))

data.t.joined = 
  filter(data.t, !is.na(ID)) %>% 
  inner_join(data.t, by = "ID")

 > head(data.t.joined, 6)
   Cols.x row.x  ID Cols.y row.y
1     ID1    X1 101    ID1    X1
2     ID1    X1 101    ID2    X2
3     ID1    X2 102    ID1    X2
4     ID2    X2 101    ID1    X1
5     ID2    X2 101    ID2    X2
6     ID1    X3 103    ID1    X3
```

This generates IDs combined from different rows which can then be processed further to generate lists of the unique IDs for the original rows (row.x in the data frame):

```
data.t.combined =
  data.t.joined %>%
  mutate(row.x = as.integer(gsub("X", "", row.x))) %>%
  select(row.x, ID) %>%
  group_by(row.x) %>%
  summarise(IDs = list(sort(unique(ID))))
```

At this point we have a number of lists containing ID sets, but these include single IDs and other subsets which will subsequently be merged together to produce a unioned final set of IDs. An extract of the intermediate IDs column is shown below:

```
> head(data.t.combined$IDs)
[[1]]
[1] 101

[[2]]
[1] 101 102

[[3]]
[1] 103 290 400

[[4]]
[1] 105 106 309

[[5]]
[1] 105 106

[[6]]
[1] 107 108
```

Now a brute force approach. The function listed below merges the subsets and removes duplicated sets. It is an inefficient approach if the number of rows in the data is very large, as it involves n * (n-1) comparisons, n^2 in effect, which would be time consuming if the number of real rows ran into the tens of thousands.

```
mergesubsets <- function(thedata){
  thedata$NewIDs = thedata$IDs
  rows = nrow(thedata)
  for (i in 1:rows){
    entry = unlist(thedata$NewIDs[i])
    for (j in 1:rows){
      if (i != j){
        otherentry = unlist(thedata$NewIDs[j])
        if(max(entry %in% otherentry)==1) {
          thedata$NewIDs[i] = list(sort(union(entry, otherentry)))
        }
      }
    }
  }
  thedata[!duplicated(thedata$NewIDs),]
}

data.t.merged = 
  mergesubsets(data.t.combined)
```

The above generates a series of lists, so the final step is to convert these to a matrix then a data frame for output. Brute force again but reasonably quick this time (I'm sure there are simpler ways to convert lists of varying length, but I couldn't find them in the time available):

```
listtodataframe <- function(thedata){
  rows = nrow(thedata)
  cols = max(sapply(thedata$NewIDs, length))
  result = matrix(nrow = rows, ncol = cols)
  for (i in 1:rows){
    entry = unlist(thedata$NewIDs[i])
    for (j in 1:length(entry)){
      result[i, j] = entry[j]
    }
  }
  data.frame(result)
}

result = listtodataframe(data.t.merged)
```

The end result mirrors what was in your post regarding the results you expected, though in mine the rows are in increasing order by ID:

```
> result
   X1  X2  X3
1 101 102  NA
2 103 290 400
3 105 106 309
4 107 108  NA
5 110 111 220
6 112 113 114
```

For comparison, this is what you posted as being expected:

```
    ID1   ID2  ID3 
1   101   102   NA
2   103   290  400        
3   105   309  106         
4   107   108   NA  
5   110   220  111  
6   112   113  114
```

I should reiterate that the loop processing is inefficient for large numbers of rows. Anyway, as in @Scipione's solution it appears from the test data to generate what you expect, and it should work with a larger real-world dataset though it may not be the most time-efficient.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  For the sample data, this did work; however it did not work for my entire data set.  I end up with duplicate IDs in the first column. This may have been because the tag IDs in my actual data set are character strings as they contain both letters and numbers. In hindsight I should have added characters to my sample data. You were correct in that this is slow for large data sets; I have over 11,000 rows and it took about 5.5 hours to run. Please let me know if you have a suggestion to improve processing time and if you think the structure of the IDs is an issue